# nebular datepicker shows invalid input when trying after closing window

Tags: javascript, angular6, nebular

Hi I am using nebular theme for both window popup and datepicker input,
On first time , trying to fill up form its working fine but when I try to fillup form , closing window and opens again datepicker field is showing invalid input.,Its really strange and I couldnot find the issue why it is happening.

Here is my code ,

```
    myForm = new FormGroup({
  Start_Date: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
});

@ViewChild('add_form') add_form: TemplateRef<any>;
openPopup()
{
  this.windowService.open(
      this.add_form,
      { 
       title: 'Add Exception Form',  
       context  : { action:'Add' }  ,
       hasBackdrop: true,
       closeOnBackdropClick: false    
      },    
      
    );
}

<ng-template #add_form let-data>
<div class="nb-window-body">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="start_date" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Start Date : </label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="Start_Date" [ngClass]="{
        'is-invalid':
          myForm.get('Start_Date').touched &&
          myForm.get('Start_Date').invalid
      }"
    required [nbDatepicker]="formpicker">
            <nb-datepicker #formpicker format="MM-dd-yyyy"></nb-datepicker>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          <div>
            You must provide Exception Start Date before submitting.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </form>
</ng-template>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using any RouteReuse strategy on your application?

Comment: Yes Raven , Youre right they are using in some other components.Is there any connection for this issue.

Comment: Yes, because by using a RouteReuse strategy, your application will try to remember inputs or states, so it might be the reason it caused this. Can you disable the route reuse and see if you are still able to see the problem? After that, I'll probably make a proper answer / response.

Comment: I tried run application without RouteReuse code . Still error comes.

Comment: and When I try to close window by using windowRef its throwing static injector error.

Comment: Can you suggest solution for this issue?